# Check palindrome using mips assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

```
.data

org_str: .space 256
rev_str: .space 256
str: .asciiz "Enter the Line: "
pal: .asciiz "palindrome"
not_pali: .asciiz "Not palindrome"

.text 
.globl main
main:
    
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str
    syscall
    
    # Taking String from the user
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, org_str
    li $a1, 256
    syscall
    
    # Initilize $t0 and $t2
    li  $t0, 0
    li  $t1, 0
    
loop_len:
    add $t1, $a0, $t0
    lb  $t2, 0($t1) # Load the data in the byte in $t2
    beqz    $t2, len_exit   # Loop till $t2 reaches zero
    addiu   $t0, $t0, 1 # increment of the counter
    j   loop_len
len_exit:

    #Return $t0 to the last Charater
    subi $t0, $t0, 1
    li $s0, 0   # Initialize variable
    addi $s0, $t0, 0    # Save the length of the String
    
    # Load the original string in $t2
    la $t2, org_str
    
    # Intialize i and j
    li $t1, 0   # i 
    li $t3, 0   # j
    
reverse_loop:
    add $t3, $t2, $t0   # $t2 is the base address
    lb $t4, 0($t3)      # load a byte
    beqz $t4, exit      # go to the exit if null was found
    sb $t4, rev_str($t1)    # Overwrite the byte
    addi $t0, $t0, -1   # decrement of j by 1 (j--)
    addi $t1, $t1, 1    # increment of i by one (i++)
    j reverse_loop      # Loop until we reach the length of the String
exit:
    
    li $t0, 0
    li $t4, 0
    li $t7, 0
    
CheckChar_loop:
    
    lb $t4, org_str($t0)
    lb $t7, rev_str($t0)
    
    beq $t4, $zero, exit_1  # go to the exit if null was found
    bne $t4, $t7, not_pal   # if $t7 and $t4 not equal
    addi $t0, $t0, 1    # increment of i by 1 (i++)
    j CheckChar_loop
exit_1:

    #li $v0, 1
    #addi $a0, $t0, 0
    #syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, pal
    syscall

    #Exit the program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
    
not_pal:
    
    #li $v0, 1
    #addi $a0, $t0, 0
    #syscall
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, not_pali
    syscall
    
    
    #Exit the program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
    
.end main
```

I am trying to check for **palindrome**. So, the idea is to revese the string and check at each index that the character in the reverse string is the same as the original one.
I am trying to check if org_str equals rev_str but it exists every single time as $t7 and $t4 even if they are equal.
rev_str is the reversed string of org_str.

Comment: 1) Please do not post images of code 2) This is not a [mcve] 3) You do not need to reverse the string, you can just iterate backwards 4) The logic seems fine at a glance. Use a debugger/simulator to see what is happening.

Comment: We can't see the whole code..  Are we supposed to guess what the problem is?

Comment: @ErikEidt the probem is that i reverse the string and then i tries to check if every character in the reversed string is requal to the original or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Basic Debugging Skills

Anyone writing assembly language should be able to single step and watch/verify their code execute.

Single step and verify that each instruction does what you expect.  Most instructions have a main effect: change the value of a register, or change the value of memory.  And all instructions tell the processor what instruction to run next.  So, we need to verify the main effect and the control flow (what instruction comes next).  (`syscall`s can change multiple memory locations and offer a return result as well.)

When you're debugging fresh code that's never been tested, use the smallest possible input to make debugging simple.

For example, test the input 'A' (0x41).  (Technically, the smallest input is the empty string, and, it would be a good idea to test that as well.)

As you evolve your program, use breakpoints to skip over code that you already know is working, then single step the new code from there.

---

In your program's case you should have noticed that the first byte of the copy is wrong, before it even stores to memory, and, you can see this by single stepping with around 35 instructions.

---

1. You have a classic off by one error, which is caused by the newline character that the read string syscall appends to the user-entered text.  Checking memory of `org_str` after the read string syscall, you should have seen this.  This newline character causes an off by one error in two places in the code — at the copy loop and at the pal check loop.  You can either make your loops count-based instead or smash the newline character with null byte to shorten the input of that character.
2. You make a count of the number of characters, then copy the characters going backward, but falsely rely on the null byte preceding the org_str to stop the copy loop.

   We only null terminate strings, one should not expect a string to be null begun as well as null terminated — unless that null beginner is explicitly provided for (not so in your case).  In general when working with strings (passed as parameters, created by other code), we cannot rely on being able to easily provide a null beginner, so it would be better programming practice instead to end the copy loop when the count (the decrementing one) reaches zero.  (easy to be off by one here so do test with the empty string as well (i.e. should be structured as a while loop, not a repeat until.))
3. Stop initializing registers to zero and then setting some other value.  You're doing the equivalent of

```
    int s0 = 0;   // <--- this initialization is pointless 
    s0 = t0 - 1;  // since s0 is immediately repurposed with a new value here
```

Btw, you never use `s0`, so even setting it to `t0-1` goes unused, but that might change when you fix the code's off-by-one errors.